# максимальный элемент в строке двумерного массива java

Tags: java, массивы

помогите пожалуйста разобраться с построчным поиском максимального элемента, никак не выходит

```
package untitled;

import java.io.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws java.io.IOException{
        int n=5, max=0, m=6, maxb=0, nn=3, cn=8;
        int[] a = new int[n]; //создание одномерного массива
        System.out.println("Одномерный массив:");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { //заполнение массива случайными числами в интервале [-7;5]
            a[i] = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 13) - 7);
            System.out.print(a[i] + "  ");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            if (max < a[i]){
                max=a[i];
        }
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Максимальный элемент одномерного массива " + max);
        int[][] b = new int[n][m];
        System.out.println("Двумерный массив:");
        for(int i = 0; i<b.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<b[i].length; j++){
                b[i][j]=a[i]>>j;
                System.out.format("%4d", b[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<b.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<b[i].length; j++){
                if (b[i][maxb] < b[i][j]){
                    maxb=j;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Максимальный элемент двумерного массива " + maxb);
        int c [][] = new int[nn][cn];
        System.out.println("Нерегулярный массив:");
        for(int i = 0; i<c.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<c[i].length; j++){
                c[i][j]=3*i+j+maxb;
                System.out.format("%4d", c[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что конкретно "не выходит"?

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял, то проблема возникла при выводе максимального значения элемента двумерного массива? Вот рабочий вариант:

```
package untitled;

import java.io.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws java.io.IOException {
        int n = 5, max = 0, m = 6, maxb = 0, nn = 3, cn = 8;
        int[] a = new int[n]; //создание одномерного массива
        System.out.println("Одномерный массив:");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { //заполнение массива случайными числами в интервале [-7; 5]
            a[i] = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 13) - 7);
            System.out.print(a[i] + "  ");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (max < a[i]){
                max = a[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Максимальный элемент одномерного массива " + max);
        int[][] b = new int[n][m];
        System.out.println("Двумерный массив:");
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
                b[i][j] = a[i] >> j;
                System.out.format("%4d", b[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
                if (maxb < b[i][j]){
                    maxb = b[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Максимальный элемент двумерного массива " + maxb);

        int c [][] = new int[nn][cn];
        System.out.println("Нерегулярный массив:");
        for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < c[i].length; j++){
                c[i][j] = 3 * i + j + maxb;
                System.out.format("%4d", c[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Результат получился в виде:

```
Одномерный массив:
-1  -5  1  6  2   
Максимальный элемент одномерного массива 6
Двумерный массив:
  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
  -5  -3  -2  -1  -1  -1
   1   0   0   0   0   0
   6   3   1   0   0   0
   2   1   0   0   0   0
Максимальный элемент двумерного массива 6
Нерегулярный массив:
   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13
   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
```

**UPDATE**

Проблема была с следующем фрагменте кода

```
    for(int i = 0; i<b.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<b[i].length; j++){
            if (b[i][maxb] < b[i][j]){
                maxb=j;
            }
        }
    }
```

А именно была допущена ошибка в условии `if (b[i][maxb] < b[i][j])` и действии выполняемом при условии. Исходя из поставленной задачи данных циклов, а именно поиск максимального значения элемента двумерного массива, необходимо определить, какое число будет больше от исходного `maxb=0;` для использования в следующих циклах. В следствии допущенной ошибки в условии переменная `maxb` оставалась всегда равной нулю, что приводило к дальнейшей ошибке выполнения алгоритма.

Проблему решил исправив условие в данном фрагменте кода, а так же действии выполняемом в случае истинности условия.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
                if (maxb < b[i][j]){
                    maxb = b[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Максимальный элемент двумерного массива " + maxb);
```

На данном фрагменте мы сравниваем значение переменной `maxb` со значением элемента двумерного массива. Если значение `maxb` меньше значения элемента массива, тогда в переменную `maxb` присваивается это значение элемента.

Comment: Можно, для приличия, хотя бы пояснить в чем была проблема и почему решение такое

Comment: Дописал в апдейте. Ошибочно решил, что проблема очевидна для всех.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте локализуем проблему. Раз вопрос стоит в поиске максимального элемента в двумерном массиве, то сосредоточимся на этом.

```
public static int getMax(int[][] arr) {
    if (arr.length == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(); // пустой массив, кидаем исключение
        // случай для всех пустых вложенных массивов не рассматриваю.
    int result = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int[] i : arr) {
        for (int j : i)
            result = Math.max(result, j);
    }

    return result;
}
```

И тест для этого метода:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = {{10,20,30}, {5,7,8,99,14}, {}, {91}};
    System.out.println(getMax(arr));
}
```

Результат:

```
99
```

PS: Старайтесь разделять большую задачу на несколько маленьких. У вас в одном методе происходит определение и наполнение двух массивов, поиск максимального по обоим и последующий вывод на экран. Все в одной куче. Продумайте несколько специализированных методов для каждой из задач и реализуйте их. Такой код легче отлаживать и поддерживать.

Answer (score 1):

Попытался сделать универсальное решение, для многомерного случая. Думаю получилось не сильно запустанно:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <R, E extends Comparable<? super E>> E getMax(R[] array) {
    Comparator<E> comparator = (e1, e2) -> e1 == null ? (e2 == null ? 0 : -1) : (e2 == null ? 1 : e1.compareTo(e2));

    E result = null;
    for (R e : array)
        if (e.getClass().isArray()) {
            E localMax = getMax((R[]) e);
            result = comparator.compare(localMax, result) > 0 ? localMax : result;
        } else
            result = comparator.compare((E) e, result) > 0 ? (E) e : result;

    return result;
}

 public static void main(String[] args){

    Integer[] a1 = new Integer[]{1, 0, 10, 100, 4, 19};
    Integer r1 = getMax(a1);
    System.out.println(r1);

    Integer[] a2 = new Integer[]{19, 199191, 999, -1, 10};
    Integer[][] a3 = new Integer[][]{a1, a2};

    Integer r2 = getMax(a3);
    System.out.println(r2);

    Integer[][] a4 = new Integer[][]{new Integer[]{1, 202, 2000, 1000000}, a1};
    Integer[][][] a5 = new Integer[][][]{a3, a4};

    Integer r3 = getMax(a5);
    System.out.println(r3);
}
```